# Search a list of list of strings inside a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, string-matching

I want to search a list of list of strings inside another list of strings in Python. If match is found, I want to retrieve the matched string of both lists. I want to get partial matches also. Both list 1 and list 2 are pretty large so just presenting a sample

Example:

```
list 1 = [ 'The tablets are filled into cylindrically shaped bottles made of white coloured\npolyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount of\ntablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white coloured\npolypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring.', 'PVC/PVDC blister pack', 'Blisters are made in a cold-forming process from an aluminium base web. Each tablet is\nfilled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters\nare opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil.', '\n']



list 2 = [['Blister', 'Foil', 'Aluminium'], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVC/PVDC'], ['Bottle', 'Cylindrically shaped Bottles', 'Polyethylene'], ['Bottle', 'Screw Type Cap', 'Polypropylene'], ['Bottle', 'Safety Ring', ''], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVC'], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVD/PVDC'], ['Bottle', 'Square Shaped Bottle', 'Polyethylene']]
```

Each match of list 2 in list 1 should be outputted as a separate stage if the matches are not present in the same string of list 1

Sample Expected output:

```
Stage 1: 'The tablets are filled into cylindrically shaped bottles made of white coloured\npolyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount of\ntablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white coloured\npolypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring.', values : ['Bottle', 'Cylindrically shaped Bottles', 'Polyethylene']

Stage 2: 'Blisters are made in a cold-forming process from an aluminium base web. Each tablet is\nfilled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters\nare opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil.', Values: ['Blister', 'Foil', 'Aluminium']
```

Match conditions:

1.) I want to match ignoring the \n in list 1.
2.) I want to match list 2 in list 1 ignoring plural/singular, which means 'Bottle' which is present as 'bottles' in list 1 should be matched.

I have tried this piece of code which I found on stackoverflow, but doesn't really work. Unable to get more than one match with this code and also not able to retrieve the entire string from list 1 which contained the values of list 2. This just lists out some values from list 2:

```
from itertools import product

def generate_edges(iterable, control):
    edges = []
    control_set = set(control)
    for e in iterable:
        e_set = set(e)
        common = e_set & control_set
        to_pair = e_set - common
        edges.extend(product(to_pair, common))
    return edges

generate_edges(list2, list1)
```

Latest changes:

```
counter = 1

for words in final_ref:
    for sen in paragraphs:
        all_exist = True
        for w in words:
            if w.lower() not in sen.lower():
                all_exist = False
                break
        if all_exist:
            #print(words[0])
            colours = ["White","Yellow","Blue","Red","Green","Black","Brown","Silver","Purple","Navy blue","Gray","Orange","Maroon","pink","colourless","blue"]
            if words[0] == 'Bottle':
                for wd in colours:
                    if wd in sen.split():
                        wd = wd

                        #print(wd)
#                        wordsnew = wd + words[0]
#                        print(wordsnew)
#            else:
#                wordsnew = words
#                print(wordsnew)
#                break



                    #print(wd)

            fr = "Stage " + str(counter) + ": " + "Package Description" + ": " + sen + " Values" + ": " + str(words) + "Colour" + ": " + str(wd) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n"
            result.append(fr)
            result = [i.replace('\n','') for i in result]
            result = [i.replace('\t','') for i in result]
            counter += 1
print(result)
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added code for your reference

Comment: Unable to get more than one match with this code and also not able to retrieve the entire string from list 1 which contained the values of list 2. This just lists out some values from list 2

Comment: I have included the same

Comment: Ok! So what attempt did you make to adapt that to your specific needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you need to show effort to get responses, but this time this will help you:

```
counter = 1
for words in list2:
    for sen in list1:
        all_exist = True
        for w in words:
            if w.lower() not in sen.lower():
                all_exist = False
                break
        if all_exist:
            print("Stage " + str(counter) + ": " + sen + " Values" + str(words) + "\n")
            counter += 1
```

Output:

```
Stage 1: Blisters are made in a thermo-forming process from a PVC/PVDC base web. Each tablet
is filled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters
are opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil. PVDC foil is in contact with
the tablets. Values['Blister', 'Foil', 'Aluminium']

Stage 2: Blisters are made in a cold-forming process from an aluminium base web. Each tablet is
filled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters
are opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil. Values['Blister', 'Foil', 'Aluminium']

Stage 3: Blisters are made in a thermo-forming process from a PVC/PVDC base web. Each tablet
is filled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters
are opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil. PVDC foil is in contact with
the tablets. Values['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVC/PVDC']

Stage 4: The tablets are filled into cylindrically shaped bottles made of white coloured
polyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount of
tablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white coloured
polypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring. Values['Bottle', 'Cylindrically shaped Bottles', 'Polyethylene']

Stage 5: The tablets are filled into cylindrically shaped bottles made of white coloured
polyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount of
tablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white coloured
polypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring. Values['Bottle', 'Screw Type Cap', 'Polypropylene']

Stage 6: Blisters are made in a thermo-forming process from a PVC/PVDC base web. Each tablet
is filled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters
are opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil. PVDC foil is in contact with
the tablets. Values['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVC']
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain your code and how you are matching 'bottle' in list2 to 'bottles' in list1

Comment: It looks for each of the words in each item of `list2` in lower case in each sentence of `list1` in lower case, and if one of the words does **not** exist, it stops looking, and start the next combination. It looks for the sequence of characters inside the sentence, so "bottle" exists in "bottles". It shouldn't have been counted?

Comment: It's working perfectly. Which line "looks for the sequence of characters inside the sentence"? Just one addition, I want to treat an entry like 'PVC/PVDC' as a single entity. Now it is coming as PVC/PVDC for stage 1 and PVC for stage 2 and PVDC for stage 3. Is that possible?

Comment: @techsmart This is what the loops do. And 'PVC/PVDC' **are** treated as a single entity, but in `list2` you also have a single entity of 'PVC' and a single entity of 'PVDC', so those matches also come up.

Comment: I need another help from you. I want to check the values of words[0] and if 'Bottle' is present in it, I want to search for the colour in that string, else I just want to return bottle without any colour values. The code which I have added under "Latest changes" extracts colour for every "Stage" which I don't want. Only if 'Bottle' is there in words[0] colour should be searched. Any idea on how to fix this